# tcolorbox: Adjust columns at a tbcposter (timeline)

Tags: tcolorbox, posters, timeline

[image]

I have a timeline over 49 years (it's 49, not 50, because I want a slight overlap in the x-direction).

How do I best adjust the grid, in other words the columns or the column width?

Should I set 49 columns? Or can I also set the columns to 1798-1810, 1810-1820, 1820-1830, ...?

Note 1: I usually only display entire decades (1800, 1810, 1820, ...); here all the individual years for a better overview.

Note 2: The connecting line of "Event 1813" is currently not so nice ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, 
showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {showframe=true, 
height=3cm, spacing=0mm, rows=3, columns=5, height=6cm,  
},
boxes = {beamer, colframe=blue!50!black, colback=blue!50, colupper=yellow!50, 
sharp corners 
},
]
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\xShift{(\tcbposterwidth)/(50-1)}
\foreach[count=\n from 0, 
evaluate={\x=int(mod(\n,50))},
evaluate={\T=int(mod(\t,10))},
] \t in {1798,...,1847}{%%
% Years, Coordinates
\draw[brown, xshift=\x*\xShift] circle(2pt) coordinate[label=] (y\t) node[font=\tiny, text=black, rotate=-45, anchor=north west]{ %t:\t, n:\n
\ifnum\T=0 \textbf{\color{red}\t} \else \t \fi%, n:\n 
};
}%%

\posterbox{name=ev1813,row=2, column=2, span=0.5}{An event in 1813.}
\draw[blue,very thick,->] (TCBPOSTER@ev1813.east) -- +(5pt, 0) |- (y1813) circle (2pt);
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how many columns you need and I don't know if you need `tcbposter`. If you know the grid that your timeline defines, you can shift nodes wherever you want.

In this case and trying to provide a better look (from my point of view) to the join between the event and the time reference, I've changed `circles` by `node[circle]` and used them as reference for a circular arrow from the text node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, 
showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {showframe=true, 
height=3cm, spacing=0mm, rows=3, columns=5, height=6cm,  
},
boxes = {beamer, colframe=blue!50!black, colback=blue!50, colupper=yellow!50, 
sharp corners 
},
]
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\xShift{(\tcbposterwidth)/(50-1)}
\foreach[count=\n from 0, 
evaluate={\x=int(mod(\n,50))},
evaluate={\T=int(mod(\t,10))},
] \t in {1798,...,1847}{%%
% Years, Coordinates
%\draw[brown, xshift=\x*\xShift] circle(2pt) coordinate[label=] (y\t) node[font=\tiny, text=black, rotate=-45, anchor=north west]{ %t:\t, n:\n
%\ifnum\T=0 \textbf{\color{red}\t} \else \t \fi%, n:\n 
%};
\path (\x*\xShift,0) node[draw, brown, circle, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt] (y\t) {}  node[font=\tiny, text=black, rotate=-45, anchor=north west]{ %t:\t, n:\n
\ifnum\T=0 \textbf{\color{red}\t} \else \t \fi%, n:\n 
};

}%%

\posterbox{name=ev1813,row=2, column=2, span=0.5}{An event in 1813.}
\draw[blue,very thick,-{Circle[open, length=5pt]}] (TCBPOSTER@ev1813.east) -| ([yshift=-.5pt]y1813.south);
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]